# What is a relation $R$ called for which $\forall x,y,z: \neg (x R y \wedge y R z)$?

Tags: relations

For a project, I am working with relations $R$ with the property:

$\neg\exists x,y,z: x R y \wedge y R z$

Does this property have a name?  If so, what is it?

Comment: These sorts of relations can be described as a bipartite graph in which all edges are directed from the same half of the graph to the other: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph

Comment: Alternatively (and still in graph theory land), your relation is a (directed) matching.

Comment: *(Directed) matching* is the kind of answer I'm looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posets this property is called having *height* $2$.

> The *height* of a poset is the maximum cardinality of a totally-ordered subset.

Comment: I like this answer. If you just think of $R$ as $<$ rather than $\leq$ (as there is no $x$ with $xRx$), then it does seem like a partial order.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: having height at most 2?

Comment: Yep! Corrected.